# Why does it paste sometimes and doesn't paste other times?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code in order to Copy/Paste a distribution list, subject line, and email body into an opened email in internet explorer.

About 80% of the time it will copy/paste everything perfectly.  The other times either the subject or distribution fail to paste.  If anyone could give me a better way to do this that would be awesome!

```
'These code is for the distro line
Sheets("Setup").Range("F8").Copy
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
tags(0).Click
tags(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'This code sets the subject line
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
Range(Cells(7, "J"), Cells(7, "M")).Select
Selection.Copy
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
tags(3).Click
tags(3).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'This code sets the email body
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
emailBodyCopy = 120
While Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J").Value = ""
       emailBodyCopy = emailBodyCopy - 1
Wend
Range(Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J"), Cells(13, "L")).Select
Selection.Copy

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set bodyarea = ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("allowTextSelection _mcp_32 customScrollBar ms-bg-color-white ms-font-color-black owa-font-compose")
bodyarea(0).Click
bodyarea(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
```

Comment: Are you filling out a form online, the click a "submit" button?

Comment: @BruceWayne I am copy/pasting data from an excel spreadsheet into a blank email that is opened. Its Outlook.com and I just hit "New Message" then run my script from excel. There is a lot of stuff happening before this. And like i said MOST of the time it pastes everything correctly, but occasionally it doesn't.  I am manually reviewing everything, so I can catch it when it doesn't work properly, but it kind of defeats the purpose of automating it if I have to fix problems every so often.

Comment: Instead of using `SendKeys` why not set the value of the web forms directly. I think for example, `tags(0).innerHTML = "mytext"` should work? Or maybe it's `.value`, but in any case look into sending data to a web form or web page in vba.